# How do I reset the GPS preferences in XCode?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, gps, xcode4.5

I'm using XCode with a bit of MapKit goodness.  For a prompt of "Would you like to allow the app to use your location?", I clicked on "Don't Allow" in the past.

I'd like to use the "Allow" option during my debugging, now.  How do I reset this setting so that the prompt comes up again?

Note: I'm relatively new, so my expectation is that this is an XCode setting.  It's possible that there's code from teammates that governs that prompt, so feel free to let me know if this is something I reset by looking through proprietary code.  Being that I'm the one that added the map view, I'm guessing this isn't the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the device, Settings > General > Reset > Reset Location and Privacy. Is that what you're asking about?

Comment: Thanks!  This worked.  Note for future non-iPhone users: this is within the simulation of the iPhone itself, not within some menu setting for the simulator.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code it detects if the User Clicked the "Dont Allow" Button:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
 {
     NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
     UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                     initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to Get Your Location, please go to Settings > General > Reset > Reset Location and Privacy" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
     [errorAlert show];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either reset the simulator via the menu. "iOS Simulator" -> "Reset Content and Settings"

Or you go to the settings app in the simulator. Then "Privacy" -> "Location" -> "Your app" and move it to on.

Comment: Doing "Reset Content and Settings" did more than just reset the location, which is specifically what I wanted.  I don't know what else gets removed or changed, so I have to accept the other answer since it specifically affects only that setting with which I was concerned.  From what I can tell, though, doing the first line of your response resets location prompts along with whatever else it does!  Regardless, I leave you with an upvote. Thank you for answering!